# 32-Bit 64-Bit Difference While Calculating Cipher

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have a simple Xades/BES implementation and two situations.

1. On Windows 7 32Bit 
   with java

   ```
   java version "1.7.0_25"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
   ```
2. On Windows 2008 Server 64 Bit, and with the same JVM.

My application works perfectly fine on 32 bit Windows 7, however when I try to run the compiled code in Windows 2008 Server I get an error:

```
    javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:349)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
```

Problematic code field is as follows:

```
    public static byte[] getDecryptedSignatureValue(XMLSignature signature) throws         XadesElementException, InvalidKeyException
{
    byte[] signatureValue = null;
    try {
        KeyInfo keyInfo = signature.getKeyInfo();            
        PublicKey key = keyInfo.getPublicKey();            
        Cipher cipher = getCipher("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        signatureValue = signature.getSignatureValue();
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(signatureValue);
        return cipherData;

    } catch (KeyResolverException | XMLSignatureException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(KeyUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        Logger.getLogger(KeyUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, "SignatureValue:"+ BaseUtils.toBase64String(signatureValue));
    } finally {

    }
    return null;

}
```

The only thing I can come up with is the architecture difference. Am I missing something here? What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here are my new findings.
1. I have tested my application on Windows 7 64 bit and there was no problem, while signing and verifying.
2. More interestingly, I have tested the application on another Windows 2008 Server 64 bit and it worked with a success.

I think there is a configuration setting for something but I could not figure it out what.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the chosen provider and/or provider implementation. Note that there is a difference between PKCS#1 padding for encryption (EME-PKCS1-v1_5 decoding) and PKCS#1 padding for signature verification (EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 encoding). Some providers will choose a padding depending on the key type (public or private), others will keep to a single padding scheme depending if you are using `Cipher` or `Signature`.

If possible try and use `Signature` for signature verification, not `Cipher` decryption with a public key. Otherwise check which providers are chosen (using e.g. `Cipher.getProvider()` and try to find one that works. Note that - as you may already have discovered - it depends on the implementation, not on the interface specification if decryption succeeds or fails.

So currently it is trying to decode this:

```
EM = 0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00 || M
```

with a random, nonzero PS and message M

You expect however to verify this:

```
EM = 0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || T
```

with a PS with values `FF`, and T being an ASN.1 DER encoded algorithm OID and hash value.

Comment: I used Signature as you advised. It solved the verification problem, however it actually showed me that the problem was not the verification I think. Because now I can sign and verify a signature on 32 bit Windows 7 (actually I was able to do this already) however I can sign but I could not verify signature on Windows 2008 Server 64 bit. Interesting thing is, I could verify the document on Windows Server 2008 64 bit which is signed on Windows 7 32 bit. I will look at the provider a little bit deeper. And if you have anything on your mind please let me know.

Comment: Have you printed out the provider used by `Signature` and `Cipher` on all the platforms?

Comment: Hello? How are you faring with this issue?